# About tirumantiram shakti mantra

Tags: scripture, vedas, shiva, mantras, yoga

I want to know about sakti mantra that tirumantiram mentions(om na ma si va)

Can anybody change or there are some specific rules since book doesn't mentions any??

Comment: you need to give the source from where your information came from. Mantras should be learned from a competent teacher, or they can have disastrous results as a result

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda    It's a book named tirumandiram written by Saint tirumalar